# How to construct this kind of irregular tables with colspan and rowspan?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to construct a table which will have complex col and row. How can I construct this kind of table?

I've already tried to construct but it seems that the output is not what I wished for. I want to make a left header which span two rows and the rows will have header and input field.

This is my code that I've already tried. I failed whenever i try to put theader to all the fields.

```html
  <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td rowspan="2">Flock ID</td>
            <td>Field 1</td>
            <td>Field 2</td>
            <td>Field 3</td>
            <td>Field 4</td>
            <td>Field 5</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Field 6</td>
            <td>Field 7</td>
            <td>Field 8</td>
            <td>Field 9</td>
            <td>Field 10</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The table should have a columnn that span two rows. For each row there will be several headers.

[This the example pic of my expected table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84zlr.png)

Comment: what is your expected view? not clear. Can you please provide an image or something.

Comment: You can have only one thead property in a table. With rowspan="2" you are expecting your initial tr's td to take next ones initial cell.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new in this site. I've upload my expected view. Hope you guys can help me whether it can be done or not.

Comment: Hi, it is a bit difficult to understand. But maybe try a table generator to help you start out for example https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables  [link](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84zlr.png you guy can check this out for my expected table